# Need help formatting results of a directory listing in PHP, javascript tree control

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to list all of the folders and files inside one particular folder using PHP. Using the code below I have managed to list all of the files and folders in one long list. Now what i am really trying to do is to list them such that i can use HTML/jquery to show the directory results as folders with + marks next to them so they can be expanded, but I cannot figure out how to format the results in PHP in order to do that.

```
 include('include/class.dirlist.php');
 $resources = "/Inetpub/companyweb/resources";
 $dir = getDirectoryListing($resources,"a",1,1,"all",1);

 $i = 0; //for illustrative purposes only 
 foreach ($dir as $item) {
     echo "<b><a href='resources/".$dir[$i]."'>".$dir[$i]."</a></b><br>";
     $i++;
 }
```

The code above will output something like this:

FOLDER1
FOLDER1/FILE1.PDF
FOLDER1/FILE2.PDF
FOLDER2
FOLDER2/FILE1.PDF
FOLDER2/FILE2.PDF

Here are my responses to the comments below:
@hek2mgl that is exactly what I am trying to do. I would like a tree type view.

@popnoodles if I can get it into a "ul li" format, that is something I believe I can work with. The thing is, I am a beginner PHPer... so looking for a working solution here.

@Bjørne Malmanger Here is the contents of the included class:

```
function getDirectoryListing($dirname, $sortorder = "a", $show_subdirs = 1,         $show_subdirfiles = 0, $exts = "all", $ext_save = 1) {
// This function will return an array with filenames based on the criteria you can set in the variables
// @sortorder : a for ascending (the standard) or d for descending (you can use the "r" for reverse as well, works the same)
// @show_subdirs : 0 for NO, 1 for YES - meaning it will show the names of subdirectories if there are any
// Logically subdirnames will not be checked for the required extentions
// @show_subdirfiles : 0 for NO, 1 for YES - meaning it will show files from the subdirs
// Files from subdirs will be prefixed with the subdir name and checked for the required extentions.
// @exts can be either a string or an array, if not passed to the function, then the default will be a check for common image files
// If exts is set to "all" then all extentions are allowed
// @ext_save : 1 for YES, 0 for NO - meaning it will filter out system files or not (such as .htaccess)

if (!$exts || empty($exts) || $exts == "") {
   $exts = array("jpg", "gif", "jpeg", "png", "doc", "xls", "pdf", "tif");
}
if ($handle = opendir($dirname)) {
   $filelist = array();
   while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {

       // Filter out higher directory references
       if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
           // Only look at directories or files, filter out symbolic links
           if ( filetype ($dirname."/".$file) != "link") {
               // If it's a file, check against valid extentions and add to the list
               if ( filetype ($dirname."/".$file) == "file" ) {
                   if (checkFileExtention($file, $exts, $ext_save)) {
                                   $filelist[] = $file;
                   }
               }
               // If it's a directory and either subdirs should be listed or files from subdirs add relevant names to the list
               else if ( filetype ($dirname."/".$file) == "dir" && ($show_subdirs == 1 || $show_subdirfiles == 1)) {
                   if ($show_subdirs == 1) {
                       $filelist[] = $file;
                   }
                   if ($show_subdirfiles == 1) {
                       $subdirname = $file;
                       $subdirfilelist = getDirectoryListing($dirname."/".$subdirname."/", $sortorder, $show_subdirs, $show_subdirfiles, $exts, $ext_save);
                       for ($i = 0 ; $i < count($subdirfilelist) ; $i++) {
                           $subdirfilelist[$i] = $subdirname."/".$subdirfilelist[$i];
                       }
                       $filelist = array_merge($filelist, $subdirfilelist);
                   }

               }

           }
       }
   }
   closedir($handle);

   // Sort the results
   if (count($filelist) > 1) {
       natcasesort($filelist);
       if ($sortorder == "d" || $sortorder == "r" ) {
           $filelist = array_reverse($filelist, TRUE);
       }
   }
   return $filelist;
  }
  else {
    return false;
 }
 }

 function checkFileExtention($filename, $exts, $ext_save = 1) {
 $passed = FALSE;
 if ($ext_save == 1) {
   if (preg_match("/^\./", $filename)) {
       return $passed;
   }
 }
 if ($exts == "all") {
               $passed = TRUE;
   return $passed;
 }
 if (is_string($exts)) {
   if (eregi("\.". $exts ."$", $filename)) {
                   $passed = TRUE;
       return $passed;
   }
  } else if (is_array($exts)) {
   foreach ($exts as $theExt) {
       if (eregi("\.". $theExt ."$", $filename)) {
           $passed = TRUE;
           return $passed;
        }
    }
  }
  return $passed;
  }
```

Comment: What is wrong with the current formatting?

Comment: Is you mean order, is http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php any help?

Comment: Can you avoid using "looks something like this" and be precise? ALso please show an example of `$dir` as a var_dump  / print_r. You might be asking for a recursive function, it's useful to know how the object looks.

Comment: Hey thats a tricky task. I'm not sure if it is helpful to just post a working solution. Do you know about recursive functions?

Comment: Ok instead of posting a working solution: You need to write a script to go through your object/array to return `li` elements that are wrapped in `ul`. When it hits a folder with children it needs to call itself. You'll end up with a of ul/li elements.

Comment: @popnoodles might be that i'm misunderstood the questioner. I understand that he wants to display the recursive directory output as a tree that can be controlled like a 'TreeView' with js

Comment: Yes that's what I got from it too.

Comment: We should also get some information about the behaviour of `class.dirlist.php`. Can it i.e. return arrays?

Comment: I guess what Im getting at is how can I format this, so that only the folder names show until they are clicked on and expanded. Its more of a formatting question.

Comment: Step 1: create the HTML formatted as (or similar to) described. Step 2: Add some javascript to show/hide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [jstree](http://www.jstree.com/). I think this is what you want. (I'm done it using jstree). Jstree is a javascript library that can be used control to render tree structures like HTML lists (`<ul>, <ol>`) or json or xml as controllable tree with '+' to open and close a folder like you wished.

Of course jstree is just the javascript part. You'll have to format the outputs of your `getDirectoryListing()` to one of the formats jstree supports. This are currently

- Json
- XMl
- Html

Here comes a basic example. When finiehd it will look like this:

[image: finished example in browser]

You can play around with the tree open and close nodes.

I've changed your directory listing function to a one that produces JSON for jstree. Its actually derived from this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987551/parse-directory-structure-strings-to-json-using-php) to get things quick working. Thanks! :) Here is the php. Place it in a folder in your webserver and name it `tree.php`

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(dir_to_jstree_array(__DIR__));

function dir_to_jstree_array($dir, $order = "a", $ext = array()) {

    if(empty($ext)) {
        $ext = array (
            "jpg", "gif", "jpeg", "png", "doc", "xls", "pdf", "tif"
        );
    }

    $listDir = array(
        'data' => basename($dir),
        'attr' => array (
            'rel' => 'folder'
        ),
        'metadata' => array (
            'id' => $dir
        ),
        'children' => array()
    );

    $files = array();
    $dirs = array();

    if($handler = opendir($dir))
    {
        while (($sub = readdir($handler)) !== FALSE)
        {
            if ($sub != "." && $sub != "..")
            {
                if(is_file($dir."/".$sub))
                {
                    $extension = pathinfo($dir."/".$sub, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                    if(in_array($extension, $ext)) {
                        $files []= $sub;
                    }
                }elseif(is_dir($dir."/".$sub))
                {
                    $dirs []= $dir."/".$sub;
                }
            }
        }

        if($order === "a") {
            asort($dirs);
        } else {
            arsort($dirs);
        }

        foreach($dirs as $d) {
            $listDir['children'][]= dir_to_jstree_array($d);
        }

        if($order === "a") {
            asort($files);
        } else {
            arsort($files);
        }

        foreach($files as $file) {
            $listDir['children'][]= $file;
        }

        closedir($handler);
    }
    return $listDir;
}
```

Here comes the basic HTML and javascript. Give it a proper name and place it beside the `tree.php`. I'm using the json_data plugin of jstree together with ajax. Also I'm using the types plugin to render different types of icons for folders and files. (It would be possible to have a custom icon for each filetype too, if you want). You'll have to place a proper folder.png and image.png beside the html file.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jstree-v.pre1.0/jquery.jstree.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function() {
          $('#dirtree').jstree({
            plugins : ["json_data", "themes", "types"],

            json_data : {
              ajax : {
                'url' : 'tree.php'
              }
            },

            'types': {
              'types' : {

                'folder' : {
                  'icon' : {
                    'image' : 'folder.png'
                  }
                },

                'default' : {
                  'icon' : {
                    'image' : 'image.png'
                  },
                }
              }
            }
          });
        }); 

    </script>
 </head>
 <body>
   <div id="dirtree"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Thats it! :) Note that you have many configuration options, styling options and plugins to jstree. You'll of course extend my example.

Please refer to the link above to the jstree project page for information about installation of jstree and the documentation.

Comment: Thanks, that is what i would like it to look like in the end, but its the getting there that is the difficult part for me. PS: I didnt give you a -1.

Comment: btw, can I change the `getDirectoryListing()` to somewhat different? The output not really fits for my needs.

Comment: this is great, thank you... But unfortunately I cannot get the jstree to work. It just keeps showing "loading". Im asuming that I enter my dir in the function in tree.php: function dir_to_jstree_array($dir = "/Inetpub/companyweb/resources", $order = "a", $ext = array()) {

Comment: firebug says: 
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
$ (function() {

Comment: nevermind, I had something missreferenced. Now it just says "loading" on the screen and firebug shows nothing.. screen is blank

Comment: PS Im actually using jquery-1.9.0.min.js by the way.

Comment: yea I did that already. Its still just "loading". did i put the actual directory in the right place in the function? is it relative to where the tree.php sits or where the testing.html sists? Or is it just relative to the C: drive?

Comment: what is the output when you access tree.php directly in browser? Do you see proper JSON or an error message?

Comment: That's the problem. Do you know how you can see error messages in PHP? if not, google on this

Comment: Well i have error logging turned on if thats what your referring to, but its not showing any errors, just a blank page. If i echo "hello"; in the code it shows hello on the page, so i know its being processed internally, just not showing anything. do I need to edit this line: echo json_encode(dir_to_jstree_array(__DIR__));

Comment: @hek2mgl I did exactly what you did, I just put my directory like function parameter and what I got is a tree, but with the name of my files, and don't show me the name of the directories. What probably should I did wrong?

Comment: @mailazs Hard to say here in comments. Why not preparing a question? (And notice me?)