# PHP Recursive arrays to UL (Logic)

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm referring from [Convert array of paths into UL list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903668/convert-array-of-paths-into-ul-list)

and i found an helpful answer with this function but from what I'm doing is doesn't work properly as I'm having a MySQL Tables structers with id, parentid, name to be able to make recursive category and sub category.

so I'm able to export the data into arrays which is has extra array called CHILDREN has the sub category arrays into it.

but when I try to use this function

```
function buildUL($array) {
        echo "\n<ul>\n";
        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
            echo "<li><a href=\"#\">";
            echo $value['name'];
            if (is_array($value))
                $this->buildUL($value['children']);
            echo "</a></li>\n";
        }
        echo "</ul>\n";
    }
```

The problem is that I got multiple output by

as empty and I want to avoid them
the output are

```
<ul> 
<li><a href="#">A
<ul> 
<li><a href="#">C
<ul> 
<li><a href="#">F
<ul> 
<li><a href="#">test
<ul> 
</ul> 
</a></li> 
</ul> 
</a></li> 
</ul> 
</a></li> 
<li><a href="#">B
<ul> 
</ul> 
</a></li> 
</ul> 
</a></li> 
<li><a href="#">1
<ul> 
<li><a href="#">2
<ul> 
</ul> 
</a></li> 
<li><a href="#">3
<ul> 
</ul> 
</a></li> 
</ul> 
</a></li> 
<li><a href="#">99
<ul> 
<li><a href="#">Another Test
<ul> 
</ul> 
</a></li> 
<li><a href="#">2 X
<ul> 
</ul> 
</a></li> 
<li><a href="#">Ham Yum
<ul> 
</ul> 
</a></li> 
<li><a href="#">Be You
<ul> 
</ul> 
</a></li> 
<li><a href="#">1 Z
<ul> 
</ul> 
</a></li> 
</ul> 
</a></li> 
</ul>
```

Comment: The problem is that the function output empty <ul></ul> in each loop

Comment: I've fixed it by using preg_replace and substr to remove the emoty <ul></ul>

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should check if is set value['children'] because as i see one line above

```
echo $value['name'];
```

$value should always be an array so you are getting into recursion on every element

try using

```
if ( isset($value['children'] && is_array($value['children']) )
```

Instead of just if (is_array($value))

Answer (score 0):

```
function buildUL($array) {
        echo "\n<ul>\n";
        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
            echo "<li><a href=\"#\">";
            echo $value['name'];
            echo "</a></li>\n";
            if (!empty($value['children']))
                $this->buildUL($value['children']);
        }
        echo "</ul>\n";
    }
```

try this one...

By the way it is not proper to have `<a ...> text <ul><li><a ...> test2 </a></li></ul> </a>`

Comment: what you did is illegal output, my main function is propa html format, but I just got a problem by receiving <ul></ul> as empty and I dont understand the logic of what causing this or how to avoid it