# Rebuild tree from a list of paths in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, path, tree

i have an array of system paths including folders and files, looking like this:

```
X:\PROJECTS\Project1_3134\2D\ConceptArt
X:\PROJECTS\Project1_3134\2D\ConceptArt\01_Designs
X:\PROJECTS\Project1_3134\2D\ConceptArt\02_Storyboards
X:\PROJECTS\Project1_3134\2D\ConceptArt\02_Storyboards\001.psd
X:\PROJECTS\Project1_3134\2D\ConceptArt\02_Storyboards\002.psd
X:\PROJECTS\Project1_3134\2D\ConceptArt\02_Storyboards\003.psd
X:\PROJECTS\Project1_3134\2D\ConceptArt\03_Moodboards
```

I would like to create a hierarchy in PHP so i can view these folders in a TreeView.

How can i rebuild a usable tree (i.e. arrays) from these paths ?

Thank you !

Comment: Check the first answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903668/convert-array-of-paths-into-ul-list and use the build_tree function

Comment: Thanks. it will do it !