# PHP What happens when an array =& itself with a key?

Tags: php

Apologies if the title is confusing. I found the [following code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903668/convert-array-of-paths-into-ul-list) by user @casablanca while trying to create a file tree from an array of path names:

```
$array = array();
foreach ($paths as $path) {
  $path = trim($path, '/');
  $list = explode('/', $path);
  $n = count($list);

  $arrayRef = &$array; // start from the root
  for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
    $key = $list[$i];
    $arrayRef = &$arrayRef[$key]; // index into the next level
  }
}
```

The result is a multidimensional array with keys that correspond to path components. What really confuses me is this particular line:

```
$arrayRef = &$arrayRef[$key];
```

Can someone help explain what exactly is happening here? The code works but I am trying to get a better understanding of why, thanks!